# Insert IF Condition, ELSE Do Nothing , MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, sql-update

I am using PHP backend, with MySQLi objects to use prepared statements. However, I have a problem, I need a query like:

```
IF ( SELECT count(*) FROM table <= 3)
   INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(5,2)
// dont do anything if (SELECT count(*) FROM table > 3)
```

It gives a syntax error at the begining and cannot understand what is wrong?

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no sense. Can you try and express your problem a different way?

Comment: @liquorvicar here you go

Comment: You can't do this in regular SQL - you generally need a language to do the 'if' part - such as PHP. However you can do with [stored procedures](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+stored+procedure) in MySQL - is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Ah, I just noticed a mention of PHP in your question. Right, well split this into two queries in PHP - do the select first, get the result, then execute the second one conditional on the first result.

Comment: @halfer yes something like stored procedures were on my mind, I hoped to handle it in q single query, but it seams it's not allowed in regular SQL (which I must use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let MySQL to do the dirty work, and avoid as much communication with the database as you can.

Go to [19.2. Using Stored Routines (Procedures and Functions)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html) and learn those tricks similar to PL/SQL. You will find much more easier to get through problems, when you have multiple queries, which depend on each other.

After some learning you will be able to write a stored procedure, that checks for a logical expression before inserting into a table.

Something like that (syntax maybe out of control here - just example):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(IN myCap INT) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE rowCount INT; 
  SELECT count(*) FROM table INTO rowCount;
  IF rowCount <= myCap THEN
    INSERT INTO [...]
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM `myTable`');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$total = $row['num'];
if($total <= 3)
{
    // Insert statament
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a single query solution, but it seems I am gonna go with this.